# how to add curr timestamp to while loop in container in pod in kubernetes?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pv-pod
  namespace: auth
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    #************** HERE is the command!
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'while true; do echo date > /output/output.log; sleep 5; done']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: pv-storage
      mountPath: /output
  volumes:
  - name: pv-storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: host-storage-pvc
```

This command is where i need to insert into a file "success! Wed Jun  8 20:28:01 WAST 2022",i.e. current timestamp.

```
command: ['sh', '-c', 'while true; do echo success! $date >> /output/output.log; sleep 5; done']
```

But it keeps writing 'success date'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440088/what-is-command-substitution-in-a-shell) for this. That would be in shell or bash, the same.

Additionally, you may need to escape the dollar sign, since `$()` has a [special meaning in Kubernetes manifests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/#define-an-environment-dependent-variable-for-a-container).

```bash
echo "success $$(date)" >> ...
```